# Custom Protobuf messages for Gazebo Sim, in separate package

Tags: gazebo, cmake

I would like to define custom Protobuf messages for Gazebo Sim in a separate 'interfaces' repository (i.e. not in the `gz-msgs` source tree), and use them in another 'application' repository.

Can someone point me to example `CMakeList.txt` files for this?

The custom messages need to import existing messages (e.g. from `gz-msgs` or another messages repository).

(This question was edited and stripped from the info that is no longer relevant given the answer below.)

Comment: Welcome to Robotics Stack Exchange! Not a perfect match but this may help: [1](https://github.com/ravijo/ros_protocol_buffer_tutorial)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was [pointed to](https://community.gazebosim.org/t/list-of-community-repositories-for-gazebo-sim/2237/2) the [SubT Competition repository](https://github.com/osrf/subt/tree/master/subt-communication/subt_communication_broker), which comes close but uses `catkin`.

But based on that I managed to get to a working solution.

I made a **fully documented example repository**, which can be found on GitHub [**here**](https://github.com/jrutgeer/gazebo_assorted_tests/tree/main/custom_protobuf_msgs).